# From README.md at github to something better?

Tags: markdown, documentation-generator, github, documentation

Several months ago I start to write down my guidelines at github:

https://github.com/guettli/programming-guidelines

The lists get longer and now I would like to improve the structure.

I guess it is time to switch from `README.md` to a other solution.

My goals:

- use git to do version control
- editable via web (SaaS). No native application should be needed.
- automated numbered headings. Up to now I am numbering the headings by hand
- splitting the long single page into several smaller pages
- I like mark-down and would like to stick to it
- Commercial services are fine.

Which software could help me?

Comment: Which OS should it run on? And I assume it should be [tag:gratis]?

Comment: Hi Izzy, thank you for asking. I updated the question.

Comment: You could use markdown with a CSS style sheet for the numbering, or a markdown to latex converter. Links or imports would work for the smaller pages. Is that the kind of structure improvement you’re looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the update! Just to make sure: you're looking for a "SaaS" (probably web-based) editor to manage Readme files in git repos, like they are used in/supported by Github, GitLab, Gitea etc. making it easier to edit those in a format supported by mentioned services, so they display them properly?

Comment: @Izzy yes I am looking for a web-based SaaS solution to make editing easier. At the moment I use one README.md file. But I think this does not scale. The file is very large. I think it makes sense to split the file into several smaller files. And I want it to use git for version control..

Comment: And I still got you wrong until I saw your comment below the "Github Wikis" answer. Problem might sit in front of my keyboard. I use the Wikis myself to document stuff – they not only work on Github, but also on Gitea (most of my projects I've moved over to Codeberg.org, which runs on Gitea). But to me (and going by the focus of this site) it seemed you're looking for a software to *manage* those Readmes…

Comment: Markdown itself is note the best format. Take a look at .asciidoctor and/or org-mode. github supports both.

Answer (score 4):

You, sir, are looking for [GitHub Wikis](https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/documenting-your-project-with-wikis).

Comment: I must have been blind. This looks like a solid solution. Thank you!

Comment: @guettli I'm glad to help. If this is an adequate solution, could you mark the answer as accepted? I just joined this exchange and I'd love the rep.